Logarithmic Function Calculation in Mathematica
I find these results in the evaluation of the logarithms that only differ in the sign $-$ I do not understand why in the first case $\operatorname{Log}[x+1]/8$ is not returned as an answer.


You miss the $+C$ in both

Actually, that is the format you normally have in Mathematica integrals answers. I did not write the answers.

This can be understood from logarithm properties. When you take an indefinite integral, there is an arbitrary additive constant at the end, so really we have
$$\int\frac{1}{8(1+x)}dx = \frac{1}{8}\ln(1+x) + C$$
Note that $\ln(8(1+x)) = \ln(8) + \ln(1+x)$, and therefore $\ln(8(1+x))+C_1 = \ln(1+x) + C_2$. So Mathematica's answers are correct: it is just a matter of simplifying it a bit.

I will add the absolute value in the $\ln$.
